# Ionic2 serve shows blank screen after using formbuilder

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I have a Login page. It was working fine. I changed the login form to use FormBuilder.

There is no error during build process or any reported in the developer tool. But the application shows blank screen when running with ionic serve.

Below is the code changed in login.html.

```
 <form [formGroup]="loginForm" (ngSubmit)="login(loginForm.value)" >
 <ion-row>
    <ion-col>
      <ion-list inset>

        <ion-item>
          <ion-input type="text" placeholder="Username" formControlName="username" ></ion-input>
        </ion-item>
        <p *ngIf="username.hasError('required') && username.touched" danger>Username is required</p>
        <ion-item>
          <ion-input type="password" placeholder="Password" formControlName="password"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>
        <p *ngIf="password.hasError('required') && password.touched" danger>Password is required</p>           
      </ion-list>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>

  <ion-row>
    <ion-col class="signup-col">
      <button ion-button class="submit-btn" full type="submit" [disabled]="!loginForm.valid">Login</button>
      <button ion-button class="register-btn" block clear (click)="createAccount()">Create New Account</button>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>

</form>
```

Below is the code changed in login.ts.

```
 import { Component } from '@angular/core';
 import { NavController, AlertController, LoadingController, Loading } from 'ionic-angular';
 import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
 import { AuthService } from '../../providers/auth-service';
 import { RegisterPage } from '../register/register';
 import { HomePage } from '../home/home';

 @Component({
 selector: 'page-login',
 templateUrl: 'login.html'
 })

 export class LoginPage {
 loading: Loading;
 registerCredentials = {username: '', password: ''};

 loginForm: FormGroup;
 username: FormControl;
 password: FormControl;

 constructor(private nav: NavController, private auth: AuthService, 
 private alertCtrl: AlertController, private loadingCtrl:   LoadingController, 
   public formBuilder: FormBuilder) {

  this.loginForm = formBuilder.group({
  username: ['', Validators.required],
  password: ['', Validators.required],
  });

  this.username = this.loginForm['username'];
  this.password = this.loginForm['password'];   
  }
```

Comment: can you share a  copy from the error on the console

Comment: ionic serve -c option shows the following error.                                    [19:39:38]  console.error: EXCEPTION: Error in ./LoginPage class LoginPage - inline template:17:15 caused by:           self.context.username is undefined
[19:39:44]  console.error: ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: self.context.username is undefine

Comment: i think you need to define the username and pssword in the constructor after loading

Comment: this.username = username;
this.password = password;

Comment: Changing username.hasError('required') && username.touched to loginForm.controls.username.hasError('required') && loginForm.controls.username.touched made this working.